# Как вывести значение переменной в виджет Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как вывести значение переменной в виджет Label?

Answer (score 1):

Если переменная строковая:

```
label.config(text=some_variable)
```

Если не строковая:

```
label.config(text=str(some_variable))
```